# Spring Data JPA Dynamic Native Query

Tags: sql, spring, jdbc, spring-data-jpa

I have native query stored in one of the tables and would like to fire the query.  I have been looking for alternatives for Pure JDBC.  my application has JPA capabilities.
Is there any framework or pattern to fire dynamic native queries?

Comment: Could you please go through the doc under the section native queries ?https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/

Comment: check out JPA's criteria builder.

Comment: My requirement is, Query would be read from one of the tables and would be fired.  Through JPA EntityManager, We can fire query to get the result.

The Problem with the current approach is, I am getting only the result.  I want to get the column name as well.